# ImageJ Create a .jar to run set of macros

Tags: java, jar, macros, imagej

I wrote several macros for ImageJ and  I would like to create a .jar (.zip) file to make easy the distribution and the installation. I can't find the way to run a macro that is located within the jar file. I looked at the ImageJ API and I maybe because I am not familiar with Java I was not able to find the answer.

The jar file contains:

1. plugins.config

   ```
   Plugins>MyPluginFolder, "Function1", my_plugin("my_macro_1.txt")
   ```
2. my_macro_1.txt

   ```
   print("Hello world");
   ```
3. The my_plugin.java and associated .class file

   ```
   import ij.*;
   import ij.process.*;
   import ij.gui.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import ij.plugin.*;
   import ij.macro.*;

   public class my_plugin implements PlugIn {
       static boolean showArgs = true;

       public void run(String arg) {
           if (arg.equals("my_macro_1.txt"))
               {my_macro_function1(); return;}
       }

       public void my_macro_function1() {
           IJ.runMacro("my_macro_1.txt");
       }
   }
   ```

I guess I am missing something. Help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed a [few](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/fiji-devel/ZTTL-GJdLOw/discussion) [times](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/fiji-devel/2YshfLDHiIY/discussion) in the ImageJ community already.

The easiest way to distribute macros, scripts and plugins is by [using your own update site](http://imagej.net/How_to_set_up_and_populate_an_update_site). In this case, there's no need to package scripts into a jar file, and users can install all your scripts at once by a single click.

If you anyway prefer to package your scripts into a jar file, have a look at the [Script Launcher](https://github.com/fiji/Script_Launcher) plugin: it allows to do exactly what you're trying to do, with supplying only the script file and a `plugins.config` file, rendering your step #3 redundant.

The problem in your code above was that ImageJ cannot see the resource file `my_macro.txt` in the jar file. You need to use the `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` method to do that. See [how it's done in the Script Launcher](https://github.com/fiji/Script_Launcher/blob/master/src/main/java/sc/fiji/script/Script_Launcher.java#L30-L60).

Comment: Note that `Script_Launcher` is not yet shipped with Fiji, but will be within the next few days.